# Sign in with Apple

Tags: email, apple-id, mobileme

I'm a bit ashamed to ask this but is there a work around for Mac.com AppleID and Sign in with Apple?

I can't use Sign in with Apple as my AppleID is Mac.com, I did setup a secondary email address for invoices etc but Sign in with Apple is stuck with Mac.com and obviously, give me an error every time I try ...

Comment: Are you saying you can’t sign in online at appleid.apple.com and need help from Apple to reset the password? Or that you have access to the account, but one or more machines won’t accept the log in in whatever pref pane, app, window you’re using?

Comment: No sorry, no issue with my actual appleID, I’m talking of « Sign in with Apple » the newish service a bit like Facebook which allow you to connect to third party website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to choose which mail to use in Sign in with Apple :

- First go to **Settings** > **Your Apple ID** > **Name, Phone Number, Emails** > Make sure the email you want to use is added.
- Open the app and click **Sign in with Apple** and then click on Share my Mail.
- It will then propose you which mail associated with you Apple ID you want to use.
  [image: Sign in with Apple Screenshot - select email]

Note that it doesn't work with the Hide my Mail feature, and you'll have to change your mail Apple ID if you want to use it.

Comment: Thank, yes the issue is with hiding the email address, I was hopping a workaround to use the hide my email feature as my AppleID still have an iCloud alias but I accept your answer because is probably just not possible alright

Comment: It's written on Apple website "If you use an icloud.com, mac.com, or me.com email address as your Apple ID, you can’t change it to a third party email address" and Hide my email only works with your Apple ID...